# Linkedin Android app crashes when using deeplink API

Tags: android, linkedin-api

1) I installed the last Linkedin Android app (version 4.0.8);
2) I installed the sample app within the Linkedin SDK (version 1.1.4);
3) The Linkedin Android app crashes when the Deeplink API is called (e.g. when I want to view my profile).
This bug was not present on the older version of the Linkedin APP.
Did someone experiment the same bug?
Is there any fast way to notify this problem?

Comment: You can show logs or code snippets...

Comment: I have no logs because it is not my app that crashes but it is the official Linkedin app. Moreover I'm using the sample app provided directly by Linkedin [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk)